# Find all the strings in $S$ that form $Q$ after deleting some of their characters

Tags: reference-request, algorithms

Given a set of Strings $S$ with a constant-size alphabet, find all the strings in $S$ that form the string $Q$ after deleting some of their characters.

If you are familiar with SQL it can also be asked as: what is the best algorithm to implement SQL `like` query with multiple `%` signs?

For example, below is a list of strings that much `fly`

- Buter**fly**
- **f**a**l**seWa**y**
- fly**fly**
- o**f**ficeP**l**a**y**

And here are some that don't

- Fly
- fl
- yfl

What is the best algorithm for solving this problem?

** You can assume that $S$ is sorted or structured in any other way.*

Comment: I think this may fit better into StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach is to scan the string from the start looking for "f".  If you find that, start from there looking for "l".  If you find that, look for "y"

Comment: Yes, this is a linear solution, a brute force in this case. I hope there are some better options out there.

Comment: Well, in general, you need to look for every single character. You could use some hash structure to store you list $S$, if you need to improve your time complexity. Note, also, that this algorithm is complete only in case $Q$ is contained only once in a string $s∈S$.

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος:  you certainly need to examine every character except perhaps two per word.  If you do not find an $f$ by the third to last character you can stop.

Comment: In general, if $n$ is the length of a string $s∈S$ and $k$ is the length of $Q$, you need to check $n-k+1$ characters for each character in $Q$. However, assuming that $n$ can get arbitrarily larger in any dataset $S$ when compared to some fixed $k$, this is no substantial improvement. So, complexity does not change significantly.

Answer (score 0):

### A simple solution

Assuming that each entry in $S$ contains at most one instance of the wanted string $Q$, you may do the following:

```
result; //Array that contains the strings that contain Q.
for each string s in S loop do:
count = 0; //Counter that keeps the current character of Q.
  for each character c in s loop do:
    if c==Q[counter] then:
      counter++;
  if counter==Q.length-1 then:
    result.add(s);
return result;
```

Evidently, the above algorithm has an $O(nm)$ complexity, where $n=\# S$ and $m=\max\{\#s\mid s∈S\}$ - the maximum length of each string in $S$.

### A more complex solution

One may wish to allow for multiple occurences of $Q$ in an entry in $S$ and may also want to know the number of ways $Q$ appears in each string. For this purpose, we will need some kind of recursion:

```
function like(s,Q,i,j,count):
//count is the number of times Q appears in s.
//s is a string in which we seek to find $Q$.
//i is an integer indicating the current character of s.
//j is an integer indicating the current character of Q we are looking for.
if k>s.length-1 then:
  return;
for each k>i-1 loop do:
  if s[k]==Q[i] then:
    if i==Q.length-1 then:
      count++;
      return;
    else:
      like(s,Q,k+1,i+1,count);
return;
```

Then, we may search $S$ using:

```
for each string s in S loop do:
  count = zeroes; //Array containing zeroes, idexed by strings in S.
  like(s,Q,0,0,count[s]);
```

Intuitively, we follow a DFS strategy and loop within the string searching initially for the first character and searching for the first character of $Q$. If we find it, we start from the point we have found it and search for the next character of $Q$ and so on.

Evidently, this is a more expensive strategy which, however, finds all occurences of the string $Q$ in $S$.

Comment: Your answer is similar to what @Ross Millkan suggested, I think that it's the most trivial approach to take, I am trying to see if there is anything better out there.

Comment: Well, look, I started writing my answer befor Ross did so I did not see s/he had already posted another answer. Why don't you update us with what you have thought about your problem. To begin with, you need to check (almost) every character in $S$, so any sublinear solution is out of our scope - provided that $Q.length$ is fixed.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I added a comment that allows you to decide the initial structure of $S$, I believe that a sublinear solution is possible under those conditions.

Comment: Well, $S$ being alphabetically sorted implies that you drop some parts of $S$ *in some cases* but the worst case scenario - hence, the big-O complexity - does change.

Comment: There is no proof saying that there is no better solution to a problem, so you can't claim that the big-O complexity will not change. We simply did not found a better way of doing it. But I am certain that one exists.

Comment: Well, in general, there are several problems for which we have proofs that prove that time and/or space complexity are bounded below by some given complexity function. Also, big-O notation has to do with the worst case scenario, which, even if $S$ is sorted, cannot be eliminated. Of course, as I mentioned earlier, hashing may improve our solution's run-time, but it may - or may not - alter complexity in general.

Comment: dude you are just messing around. Let me redefined this: There are $S$ strings from which $X$ strings are matching the string $Q$ by removing some, or non of their characters. The best possible solution to this problem is $O(X)$, a trivial solution is $O(S)$, I would like to find a sub-linear solution to $S$.

Comment: In your initial question you write: "Given a set of Strings S
with a constant-size alphabet, find all the strings in S that form the string Q after deleting some of their characters." Decide upon $S$ being the set or the count. Also, please, be kind, we are here to help you and we need you to be clear so as to do so. Lastly, in this new context, you have not clarified whether we know which are these $X$ items that match $Q$. If so, $S\setminus X$ strings are redundant.

Comment: we don't know which are the $X$ items that match $Q$, this is what this question is about.

Comment: Then, you cannot avoid checking any of the entries, since any one of them is candidate for being a mathcing string. So, if $S$ contains $n$ elements, you have to check all of them, so $O(n)$ time complexity, at least!

Comment: Create a data structure that maps a later to the strings in S that contains that later. Then when searching for Q it will skip the strings in S that don't have all the laters in Q. In best case scenario it will be O(1). So skipping strings in S, is very much possible

Comment: "In best case scenario..." Big-O notation is the worst case scenario, not the best. What you have above is $\Omega(1)$, not $O(1)$. Also, note that you take into account only time complexity. Even if you somehow manage to reduce time complexity, space complexity will increase - so as to store the information you seek at each step. In general, the action of "checking" cannot be conducted at no cost - since the data structure you mention just hides that cost.

Comment: I was just illustrating for you that skipping strings in S is possible. And as the question states, you can pre process S to put it in what ever structure you like. The idea is there going to be many searches for different Q's.